# Mail::queue not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

i'm unable to queue emails in laravel 5.4. in previous laravel 5.3 projects all worked fine.

Send is still working:

```
Mail::send('email.blank', ['title' => 'nice', 'content' => 'message'], function ($message)
        {
            $message->from('a@b.com', 'test');
            $message->to('a@b.com');
        });
```

Queue does not work:

```
Mail::queue('email.blank', ['title' => 'nice', 'content' => 'message'], function ($message)
        {
            $message->from('a@b.com', 'test');
            $message->to('a@b.com');
        });
```

With the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in Mailer.php line 314:
Only mailables may be queued.
in Mailer.php line 314
at Mailer->queue('email.blank', array('title' => 'nice', 'content' => 'message'), object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 221
at Facade::__callStatic('queue', array('email.blank', array('title' => 'nice', 'content' => 'message'), object(Closure))) in EmailController.php line 16
at EmailController->mailtest()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EmailController), 'mailtest'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('mailtest', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(EmailController), 'mailtest') in Route.php line 203
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 160
at Route->run() in Router.php line 559
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
```

I've created the queue table by

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

and changed the driver to database

***UPDATE***
it looks like in laravel 5.4 you are only able to queue emails using mailables

```
php artisan make:mail TestMail
```

within the newly created class change the build function to return an existing view e.g

```
public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('email.test');
    }
```

then queue the mail

```
 Mail::to('a@b.com')->send(new TestMail());
```

thanks

Comment: Did you setup queue daemon or listener to monitor the queue ? https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queues#running-the-queue-listener. Can you see your queues in db table?

Comment: no, there's no job in the queue... same for sync driver!  the error message is a bit weired "Only mailables may be queued."

Comment: from laravel 5.3 onward, you are suppose to use `Mailable` class to create and send mail. read about it here https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/mail#generating-mailables

Comment: @markus did you solved it? I am getting the same error. I think that queue works only with mailable.

Answer (score 1):

the queue email is use this script

```
Mail::to('a@b.com')->queue(new TestMail());
```

instead of

```
Mail::to('a@b.com')->send(new TestMail());// this just commonly sent email not queueing
```