# InvalidArgumentException: Only mailables may be queued

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.4

While updating from laravel v 5.1 to v 5.4 I got this error:

> InvalidArgumentException: Only mailables may be queued.

It was passing before the update so how i can fix it?

Comment: Please make this question more specific, Is the error only showing that? How the process when you update from v 5.1 to v5.4

Comment: yes its 
1) RouteForecastTest::storeRouteForecastTest
InvalidArgumentException: Only mailables may be queued.

/home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Mail/Mailer.php:338
/home/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:221
/home/app/Http/Controllers/RouteFController.php:164
/home//tests/RouteFTest.php:134

Comment: I think this is the problem in laravel v 5.4, here's the similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227186/mailqueue-not-working